# In Ben-Hur, does the Sheik ever collect his 4,000 talents?

Tags: plot-explanation, ben-hur

In the movie *Ben-Hur* (1959), the Sheik bets Messala a thousand talents at 4:1 on the outcome of the chariot race.

At the end of the race, Messala both loses and dies.

Does the Sheik ever collect his four thousand talents?

Comment: It is very unimportant to the plot of the movie.  They symbolism is that Messala is totally ruined after the race.  Paid or not, his estate is either bankrupt or near-so.

Answer (score 2):

### Most certainly yes

There isn't a scene in the film that explicitly shows him collecting the debt because its not really important to the story, but that said, with what we know about the Sheikh and Messala as well as the scene where the bet is made, there is every reason to assume that he collected the money owed to him.

1. The Sheikh has a desire to beat Messala and humiliate him.
2. The Sheikh is a worldly man, with many wives, riches, servants, etc.
3. When the bet is made, Messala leaves a mark on a tablet with his ring, essentially the same as signing a contract.
4. Even though Messala dies, his estate would be obligated to settle the debt.

Comment: How much was a thousand talents?  Was it probable that Messala even had a thousand talents?

Comment: Is that even relevant? He was legally bound to settle the debt if he lost.

Comment: There is a saying "you can't get blood from a stone".  If Messala didn't have a thousand talents it would be hard to force his estate to pay a thousand talents.  Was it even possible for a Roman or a sheikh to be worth a thousand talents, or was that an obviously impossible amount to possess?

Comment: He agreed to the debt so we can assume he had the money.

Comment: I'm with @M.A.Golding on this one - if this was akin to betting "100 billion dollars", then there was no way that the Sheik could pay up. However,  "Talent" is a measure of weight  (about 30 kg in Roman times), not a single coin, so Sheik could bet for example 30 000 kg of beef... which is still a hell lot of beef.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talent_(measurement) "A Roman talent (divided into 100 librae or pounds) was 1+1⁄3 Attic talents, approximately 32.3 kg (71 lb 3 oz)." This much silver is about $25k at current prices, so 1000 talents would be $25m.

Comment: @Yasskier From the wikipedia article: "The talent (Ancient Greek: τάλαντον, talanton, Latin talentum) was a unit of weight used in the ancient world, often used for weighing gold and silver, but also mentioned in connection with other metals, ivory,[1] and frankincense. In Homer's poems, it is always used of gold" and "The name comes from the Semitic root KKR meaning 'to be circular',[13] referring to round masses of gold or silver.[14]" The term talent is similar to the word "pound". Sure, you could talk about a pound of beef, but in Britain, it derives from what was once a pound of silver.

Answer (score 0):

How much money was a talent?

Here is a discussion of the terms of the treaty that ended the First Punic War:

> The next order of business was money. Rome wasn’t going to let Carthage walk away without handing over a large amount of talent.  Carthage was to pay the Romans 3,200 talents over the next ten years. They also had to pay an indemnity of 1,000 talents immediately. Rome didn’t expect the Carthaginians to be able to pay the talents quickly. However, they paid it off much quicker than anticipated due to their new trade networks.

https://sites.psu.edu/cams101groupi2014/rome-responsibility-for-war/reparations-for-the-first-punic-war/[1](https://sites.psu.edu/cams101groupi2014/rome-responsibility-for-war/reparations-for-the-first-punic-war/)

So a peace treaty required one large country to pay another large country one thousand talents immediately, and then pay three thousand two hundred talents over a period of ten years, which would amount to a rate of 320 talents per year or 26.666 talents per month or about 0.876 talents per day.

So if the Romans thought that a thousand talents was a vast amount of money suitable as reparations after a war in which hundreds of thousands of Romans died, each talent must have been a very large sum of money.

So was there a lot of inflation between 241 BC and about AD 33, the approximate date of *Ben-Hur*?

Did individual aristocratic Romans tend to get a lot richer in those 275 years, and if so, did they get enough richer?  Was Messala a member of the senatorial class or the equestrian class?  How rich was Messala supposed to be compared to other Romans serving as tribunes?

It is my impression that neither the Sheikh nor Messala would have been able to pay off a bet of 1,000 talents or 4,000 talents.

But an ancient historian would be better qualified to answer that question.

Comment: This is a very speculative answer and only seems to pose more questions rather than answer the OP's original question. The question is not COULD they pay, but rather DID the Sheikh collect the debt after Messalah's death. In other words, was the bet still good even though Messalah died. Your focus on whether Messalah had 1000 talents or not seems distracting and irrelevant to me. The point is it was a lot of money, but Messalah agreed to the bet with his signature. The end. He would have either paid or gone to debtors prison.

Comment: @sanpaca  If Messala & Sheikh bet more money than either owned or more money that it was possible for anyone except for Emperor  Tiberius or King of Kings Artabanus III to own, it would be impossible to collect the bet because the money wouldn't be there.  The Sheikh could not have collected if it was impossible for him to collect.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the novel, you would know what happened to Messala’s 4,000 talents, which he was tricked by his own pride to wager. Yes, he paid the debt as he had bound himself to do, but he did not die. Instead, he was a cripple for the rest of his life.

I looked up to see how much 4,000 talents would be in modern times: 4 billion US dollars. Gasp. I wondered how a soldier came by that kind of money, but okay. Maybe he also cheated.

Anyway, Judah got a sizable cut of that for being the charioteer and trainer. In addition, Simonides hid Judah’s personal fortune from the Romans. In the book, he does not sever ties with Arrius, so he also inherits Arrius’ fortune. Since consuls were second in power, respect, and riches only to the emperor, that money is also considerable, and of course he also inherits the properties and position, not of the consul because that was an individual reward, but of the son of a very powerful and respected man.

Judah marries Esther, and moves his family to Rome, and Judah uses his Roman citizenship, money, and position to help found the Roman church. It is unclear if he lived to see the persecutions of Nero’s reign.

So yes. The Sheik collected, and the bet financially ruined Messala. It is certainly the best example of karma I ever saw.

Comment: Can you provide some quotes to back up these assertions?

Comment: *"The master laughs, and is well pleased. If the Roman pays, he is ruined; if he refuses to pay, he is dishonored. The imperial policy will decide the matter. To offend the East would be a bad beginning with the Parthians; to offend Sheik Ilderim would be to antagonize the Desert, over which lie all Maxentius's lines of operation. Wherefore Simonides bade me tell you to have no disquiet; Messala will pay."* for example

Answer (score -2):

A "Talent" is a unit of weight, not currency - Roman currency was called "Denarius".

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talent_(measurement)):

> The talent was a unit of weight that was introduced in Mesopotamia at the end of the 4th millennium BC, and was normalized at the end of the 3rd millennium during the Akkadian-Sumer phase. It was divided into 60 minas, each of which was subdivided into 60 shekels. The use of 60 illustrates the attachment of the early Mesopotamians to their useful sexagesimal arithmetic. These weights were used subsequently by the Babylonians, Sumerians, and Phoenicians, and later by the Hebrews.[...]A Roman weight talent in ancient times is equivalent to 100 librae; a libra is exactly three quarters of an Attic weight mina, so **a Roman talent is 1.33 Attic talents and hence approximately 32.3 kg (71 lb 3 oz)**.

So the bet sounds a bit like "I bet 1,000 kg". Kilograms/Talents of what?

If we indeed talking about Roman Talents of Gold/Silver then it is really doubtful that Messal could pay, if it was Talents of, let's say grain - quite probably.

But if we assume that indeed it was a reasonable value, then indeed Messala or whoever was taking from him would have to pay up.